# How can I multidimensionalise this code that finds indices from a list of values?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have some code that finds the indices of elements in the "input" list that match any element in the "values" list. The indices are then outputted, arranged in the same order as the "values" list.

```py
input = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 9]
values = [4, 8, 3]

match_index_lst, match_index_values = np.where(np.array(input) == np.array(values)[:,None])

output_indice_lst = match_index_values[np.argsort(match_index_lst)]
# [5, 2, 4]
```

My question, is whether it's possible to efficiently(using vectorized operations) expand this code to use it in specific multidimensional lists? Currently the input list is of dimension `c`, but I will be having inputs with dimensions of `[a, b, c]`. So instead of something like:

```py
input = [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 9]
values = [4, 8, 3]
# output: [5, 2, 4]
```

I will have something like

```py
input = [[[[ 0.31, 1.56, 1.58, 0.16, 0.22, 0.54, 0.98, 0.35 ]],
          [[ 0.77, 2.62, 0.44, 0.08, 0.76, 0.87, 0.88, 0.51 ]]],

         [[[ 1.14, 0.48, 1.09, 0.93, 0.47, 0.13, 0.75, 0.19 ]],
          [[ 1.15, 0.17, 2.33, 0.46, 0.30, 2.60, 0.79, 1.07 ]]]]

values = [[[[ 0.54, 1.58 ]],
           [[ 0.77, 0.88 ]]],

          [[[ 0.48, 1.09 ]],
           [[ 2.60, 2.33 ]]]]


# output: [[[[ 5, 2 ]],
#           [[ 0, 6 ]]],
#
#          [[[ 1, 2 ]],
#           [[ 5, 2 ]]]]
```

My specific example is of size `(2, 2, 8)`, but it could be any `(a,b,c)` size.

I've tried flattening it and then performing operations on it, but I just can't seem to get the order right after unflattening it, and then getting the output properly formatted is also a nightmare. I can see how it would be pretty easy to implement with for loops, but I want to keep that as a last resort as speed is crucial.

Comment: using broadcasting and `where` is very inneficient in this situation. Use index matching

Comment: Your values do is 4 dimensional while input has 3 dimensions. That is an issue

Comment: @Onyambu my mistake, I edited it so it's all 4d now

Comment: your input has no commas. Could you include the commas please

Comment: Even though an array is displayed without commas (the `str` form), copy-n-paste is not convenient.  Show a list form, or the `repr` format.  You'll get better response from potential answerers..

Comment: Its not clear as to why you would want `0.88` to have id 6. 0.88 is not in the list

Comment: @Onyambu. Fixed it. The ```values``` were rounded, and the ```input``` wasn't. That's why some numbers were 0.01 wrong.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is not correct in the case you have some values equal. eg change `0.88` to `1.58`  in both the values and input array and see the results given by the accepted answer is incorrect

Comment: @Onyambu Very important for future visitors, but I am working with randomly generated torch.float64 numbers, and the odds of 2 being the same are 1 in 2^64... So not gonna happen in my lifetime ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea with using the flattened index was right. Here is what that would look like:

```py
import numpy as np

input = np.array([[[[ 0.31, 1.56, 1.58, 0.16, 0.22, 0.54, 0.98, 0.35],
                    [ 0.77, 2.62, 0.44, 0.08, 0.76, 0.87, 0.87, 0.51]],
                   [[ 1.14, 0.48, 1.08, 0.93, 0.47, 0.13, 0.75, 0.19 ],
                    [ 1.15, 0.17, 2.32, 0.46, 0.30, 2.60, 0.79, 1.07 ]]]])

values = np.array([[[[ 0.54, 1.58 ]],
                    [[ 0.77, 0.88 ]]],
                   [[[ 0.48, 1.09 ]],
                    [[ 2.60, 2.33 ]]]])

sort_idx = np.argsort(input.flat)
output_flat = sort_idx[np.searchsorted(input.flat, values.flat, sorter=sort_idx)]
output = np.unravel_index(output_flat.reshape(values.shape), input.shape)[-1]
print(output)
```

Which prints:

```
[[[[5 2]]

  [[0 3]]]


 [[[1 0]]

  [[5 5]]]]
```

(please check your reference output it does not seem right to me, especially there is the question, what should happen I the value is not in the index)

The key missing part was the `np.unravel_index()` and reshaping to the `values.shape`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the ```values``` will always be in the ```input``` because this is part of a custom 2d maxpool function. The example I used had some incorrect numbers as some ```values``` were rounded and ```input``` was not. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `np.where` with broadcasted `==` is very inefficient. Consider using `searchsorted`:

```
def match(arr, vals):
    k = arr.shape[-1]
    def fn(x):
        x, y = x[:k], x[k:]
        idx = x.argsort()
        return idx[np.searchsorted(x[idx], y)]
    return np.apply_along_axis(fn, len(arr.shape) - 1, np.c_[arr,vals])

match(np.array(input_arr), np.array(values))
array([[[5, 2],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [5, 5]]], dtype=int64)
```

---

Note that you could use `lambda` function as below:

```
def match(arr, vals):
    k = arr.shape[-1]
    fn = lambda x : (i1 := x[:k].argsort())[np.searchsorted(x[:k][i1], x[k:])]
    return np.apply_along_axis(fn, len(arr.shape) - 1, np.c_[arr,vals])

match(np.array(input_arr), np.array(values))
array([[[5, 2],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [5, 5]]], dtype=int64)
```